# Product Layout Magento

Tags: magento, layout

I am facing difficulties in my website. If you open my website www.gamearcade.co , you will find that the New Products layout on the homepage are displayed in grid view, but in a strange way. If you check, you will find on my website that the product images are not centred and the "Add to Wishlist" and "Compare" are not in their right place.
How can I edit this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should edit: `app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Except if you have installed any module that overrides this file.